# Kernel keeps dying

Tags: python, function, if-statement, jupyter

what function do you use in Jupyter notebook in place of quit() because the quit() function keeps killing my kernel but it works perfectly in the pycharm and VS code

I wrote the quit function under an if statement. And the quit() function instead of ending the program when the condition is met, it rather kills my kernel

Comment: If you don't work with the interactive interpreter you shouldn't use `quit` anyway. To cite the [documentaion of `quit` and `exit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/constants.html#quit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Answer (score -1):

I think raising an error when your `if` statement is verified can be a good solution.

For example :

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt
```

Having a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html may help you.